# Setting property for class name binding

Tags: ember.js

I'm having some trouble getting my class name binding to properly change the class on a div based on a property that either returns true or false.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  isConnected: function() {
    return false;
  }.property(),
  actions: {
    var self = this;
    [some ajax action]
    success: function(data){
      self.set('isConnected', true);
    }
  }
  ...
});
```

And in the template I have the typical class name binding setup

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar {{if isConnected 'progress-bar-success' 'progress-bar-danger'}}" style="width: 101%;"></div>
</div>
```

It doesn't seem to be working, and I'm getting no errors

Comment: syntax for actions is incorrect here. It should be `actions: { actionName: function(){ .... }}` .
see here http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/actions/

Comment: @kushdilip you're linking to the old docs

Comment: `isConnected` should be on the controller and doesn't need to be a computed property.

Comment: @Kitler my mistake. google search actually gave v1.10.0 docs by default.

Comment: Considering that 2.0 has been out for ~2 weeks of course you are going to land on the 1.10 docs, make sure to select 1.13/2.0 in the dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [ember twiddle](http://ember-twiddle.com/50932277fc503db9daf7) for this, which explains how class binding in this case works.

Controller has the property `isConnected` set to false by default. The action on same controller modifies `isConnected` which gets reflected in view template.

In your case the property defined on `route` hence not connected to the view templated.